# Matrix that makes use of an struct

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, struct, declaration

I have a matrix, and a `struct` with 2 `int` variables.

```
struct virus {
int gen;
int neighbours;
}
```

I want to initialize my full `gen` matrix with the `1` value. The problem is it doesn't work for the first column of the matrix.
I'll post down bellow the code. 
Also when I tried to set my matrix as the `virus struct` it didn't work and I had to initialize a new matrix that I called `b`.
It's just a simple initialization and a printing.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

struct virus {
    int gen;
    int neighbours;
    };

void initGen(int n, int a[][100])
{
    struct virus b[n][100];

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
              b[i][j].gen = 1;
            }
    }
}

void printMatrixGen(int n, int b[][100])
{
    struct virus a[n][100];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j].gen);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[100][100], n;
    n = 4;
    initGen(n,a);
    printMatrixGen(n,a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the matrix

```
0    1    1   1
0    1    1   1
0    1    1   1
0    1    1   1
```

Instead of

```
1    1    1   1
1    1    1   1
1    1    1   1
1    1    1   1
```

Comment: Why do you pass an array as parameter, ignore it and then initialize a local array instead? This code doesn't make any sense and that's the reason for your errors.

Comment: BTW:  _it didn't work_ is not a problem description. You need to tell us what actually happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I just edited the code and added the output that the program gives me and the one it shoud.

Comment: I have to pass my matrix as a parameter as I can't make use of any global variables.

Comment: In both the functions `printMatrixGen` and `initGen` you are working only with the local array.

Comment: Suggest reading about the 'scope' of variables.  Especially as pertains to local variables within a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code passes a wrong array. You need to change function signatures as follows:

```
void initGen(int n, struct virus a[][100]);
void printMatrixGen(int n, struct virus a[][100]);
```

After that, remove local declaration of `struct virus b` arrays, and use `struct`s passed as parameters.

Finally, declare your `struct` array inside `main`, and pass it to both functions:

```
struct virus a[100][100];
int n = 4;
initGen(n, a);
printMatrixGen(n, a);
```

Comment: Great help! Thank you! Now I understand how I should make use of structs thanks to you.

Comment: this expression: `struct virus a[100][100], n = 4;` is not correct as it is declaring variable 'n' to be a instance of a 'struct virus'  Suggest moving that expression to a new line similar to: `int n = 4;`

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you very much!